# Create a utility function that retrieves the user-executed script's dir

Tags: python

There are multiple threads about getting the current Python's script directory, for example:

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

The question is, what should I do if I want to add this function into some utility file, while I want the returned value to be the directory of the calling file, in this case, the file executed by the user?

What would happen here?

// utils.py

```
def get_script_dir():
    import os
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

// main_app.py

```
from utils import get_script_dir
print(get_script_dir())
```

// user's shell

```
python c:\path\to\somewhere\main_app.py
```

Will it print the directory of `main_app.py` or the directory of `utils.py`? What is an elegant solution for placing the function in the `utils` file while getting the directory of the file that was actually executed by the user?

Comment: Is there a return from the get_script_dir() ?

Comment: why not pass `__file__` as argument to `get_script_dir`?

Comment: why not just experiment few scenarios?

Comment: You should try out the code you wrote in your question to see which directory will be printed out for yourself. The answer is that the directory of the utility file will be printed, since the `__file__` object is looked up from within this file, giving you the problem you foresaw.

Comment: @roymustang86 yes - fixed it

Comment: @hiroprotagonist and jmd_dk - I can try it but hoped there's a more elegant way

Answer (score 1):

Please try following and let me know whether it's exactly what you want:

```
# utils.py
def get_script_dir():
    import sys
    import os
    return os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)

# main_app.py
from utils import get_script_dir
print(get_script_dir())
```

Comment: Did you leave out `os.path.dirname()` intentionally? Your code seems to display `__main__`'s filename, not its directory.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your project directory tree is like the following:

```
Python/
    main.py
    modules/
        utils.py
        __init__.py
```

Being `Python/modules/utils.py`:

```
import os
get_script_dir = lambda file: os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))
```

and `Python/main.py`:

```
from modules import utils
import os

script_dir = utils.get_script_dir(__file__)
print("[i] Currently executing file {} located at {}".format(os.path.basename(__file__), script_dir))
```

Executing `Python/main.py` is going to output something like:

```
[i] Currently executing file main.py located at C:\Users\BlackVirusScript\Desktop\Python
```